# Library links to /usr/lib64, but I need the one from /usr/local/lib64

Tags: linux, linker

I'm getting this weird problem

```
ag: /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5: no version information available (required by ag)
```

For some reason the preinstalled library is no good. Okay, so I install liblzma from source, but how do I link against it? The makefile already says:

```
-L/usr/local/lib64 -llzma
```

But here's the result, it will still take /usr/lib64 by default apparently: ldd ag

```
liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5
```

Answer (score 1):

update your /etc/ld.so.conf  to make /usr/local/lib64  before /usr/lib64 ?
and then run ldconfig as root

Comment: Updating `/etc/ld.so.conf` will affect *every* installed application, and may have unpredictable consequences now, or in the future.

Comment: If the new library is corrent, actually I don't see the reason why not replacing the incorrent one ...

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason the preinstalled library is no good.

Your best bet is to try to figure out *why* preinstalled library is no good, and fix the root cause.

If you can't, your next best bet is to build your executable `ag` with `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib64`.

Updating `/etc/ld.so.conf` (as suggested by frostyplanet) is probably the worst solution possible: it will affect *every* executable on your system. If you start installing more stuff into /usr/local/lib64, currently-working applications may suddenly break in unpredictable fashion.